# Error code 405 when deploying vue and nginx with docker - Any solutions?

Tags: nginx

I am currently working on a project at my company, and I have to deploy vue, nginx using docker.

I haven't been able to distribute it since yesterday...He's crying.

Error name is ngnix 405 error... I tried adding error_page 405 = $uri; as a workaround... 200 status_code occurs, but the divisor does not store the value. I would appreciate it if you could let me know if anyone knows.

Thank you.

I expected to receive 200 by sending post, not 405 errors.

[Dockerfile]

```
FROM node:16 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY  ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[Nginx]

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  client_max_body_size 1024M;

  location / {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    error_page 405 = $uri
  }
}
```

[vue.config.js]

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your API is not running. Start it and try again.